# Does simplicity always improve Readability?

Tags: code-quality, readability

Recently, I was developing a set of coding standards for our company.  (We're a new team branching out into a new language for the company.)

On my first draft, I set the purpose of our coding standards as improving Readability, Maintainability, Reliability, and Performance.  (I ignored writability, portability, cost, compatibility with previous standards, etc.)

One of my goals while writing this document was to push through the idea of simplicity of code. The idea was that there should be only one function call or operation per line.  My hope was that this would increase readability.  It's an idea that I carried over from our previous language.

However, I've questioned the assumption behind this push:

**Does simplicity always improve readability?**

Is there a case where writing simpler code decreases readability?

It should be obvious, but by "simpler", I don't mean "easier to write", but less stuff going on per line.

Comment: If the alternative is "clever" code, then yes...

Comment: yes - per Occam's Razor - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: Try to avoid using such rigid terms as always and never.  This is to avoid focusing on edge cases and instead focus on the most common issues we face.  This is what best practices are all about.

Comment: actually, you want 2 functions/operations per line. `a = b` is one operation, `b + c` is a second, which means `a = b + c` is 2 operations. Chaining 2 functions/operators is still readable: `foo(bar())`, or `a = foo()`.

Comment: Also, don't worry too much. If you try to eliminate every bit of subjectivity from your explanations, just like if you try to specify every possible detail of coding style in a million or more rules, your standards will be overcomplex, unreadable, ignored and therefore pointless.

Comment: Two common pitfalls for programmers: making simple tasks complex. But also simple solutions for complex problems.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"Simple" is an overused word. "Readable" can profitably be defined as "simple to understand", in which case increasing (this measure of) simplicity by definition increases readability, but I don't think this is what you mean. I've [written](http://lateornever.blogspot.com/2010/10/mastery-against-generality-or-keep-it.html) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230863/ruby-rails-inject-on-hashes-good-style/3230982#comment3345504_3230982) this [elsewhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/97973/14820), but generally something can be called "simpler" either by being more abstract (in which case fewer concepts can express more phenomena) or by being more concrete (in which case a concept does not require as much background knowledge to understand in the first place). I'm arguing that, depending on perspective, a more abstract concept can reasonably be called simpler than a more concrete concept, *or vice versa*. This, even though "abstract" and "concrete" are antonyms.

I'll use as an example some Haskell code I wrote a while ago. I [asked a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856071/implementing-a-per-digit-counter-using-the-list-monad) about using the List monad to calculate a counter in which each digit could have a different base. My eventual solution (not knowing much Haskell) looked like:

```
count :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
count [] = [[]]
count (x:xs) =
  -- get all possible sequences for the remaining digits
  let
    remDigits :: [[Integer]]
    remDigits = count xs
  in
  -- pull out a possible sequence for the remaining digits
  do nextDigits <- remDigits
     -- pull out all possible values for the current digit
     y <- [0..x]
     -- record that "current digit" : "remaining digits" is
     -- a valid output.
     return (y:nextDigits)
```

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857498/223783) reduced this to:

```
count = mapM (enumFromTo 0)
```

Which of these is "simpler" to understand (i.e. more readable) depends entirely on how comfortable the reader has become with (abstract) monadic operations (and, for that matter, point-free code). A reader who's very comfortable with these abstract concepts will prefer to read the (short) more abstract version, while one who is not comfortable with those operations will prefer to read the (long) more concrete version. There is no one answer about which version is more readable that will hold for everybody.

Comment: Some developers will progress until they understand and prefer the one-liner.  Hard to imagine a developer who understands the one-liner coming to prefer the long version.  Therefore IMO the one-liner is clearly better.

Comment: @kevincline - assuming the developer is working in isolation, I agree, the shorter version is (probably) better. If she's working as part of a team, and the team is not at the level where they understand and prefer the one-liner, and they must all be able to maintain the code, then the long version is (probably) better in that circumstance.

Comment: @Aidan Cully : Also think of the team that will replace you when you move on, so even the dev working in isolation needs to think "team".

Comment: As a counterpoint: given that you're an experienced Haskeller, you can read the second version in a glance. The first version, on the other hand, would require reading and understanding significantly more code; you could not do it in a glance. I think that makes the second version simpler.

Comment: @kevin - not so much in this particular case, but in general the longer version can be both more readable and more flexible. The one-liner relies on code that you can't easily read because it's not on the page you're reading, so if the name doesn't fully describe all relevant aspects of what it does, you either have to go hunting for that or for documentation or (as so often happens) guess wrong an end up with an out-by-one-on-the-bounds error or whatever. As for flexibility - you can't tweak the details if those details are in a function that others are dependent on.

Comment: @Steve314: `mapM` is pretty idiomatic, and `enumFromTo` does exactly what it says on the tin. In general, I find it's actually *easier* to make off-by-one errors if you expand code out--there's simply more code to make a mistake in. This is especially evident with things like for loops vs higher-order procedures in other languages, but I find it to be a general principle.

Comment: @Tikhon - as I said, "not so much in this particular case". Even so, my habit is to assume half-open bounds, and Haskell is far from an everyday language for me so I don't know everything off the top of my head. So I could easily get an out-by-one error through wrongly guessing that `enumFromTo` uses half-open bounds (it actually uses inclusive bounds). As it happens, I'd make the same error with `[0..x]` (at least I assume that's inclusive too, not sure) - but that's just sugar for an even longer form that would make the bounds explicit.

Comment: Oh, I read your "not so much..." as meaning that programmers wouldn't prefer the longer solution in this case, rather than the opposite.

Comment: @Tikhon - where I'm probably being unfair - many languages have a general convention for bounds styles, in which case I should just learn that Haskell has a general inclusive-bounds convention and ensure any function that has good reason to do otherwise makes it explicit in the name. Nevertheless, I am arguing from experience - I've had hassles many times because it wasn't obvious from name or context what the bounds were.

Comment: @Steve314: I see what you're saying. On the other hand, with a library solution like this you *could* know how it worked; if you have some experience and the library function is common, you probably would. However, with something more expanded like a loop, you'd have to read the code to figure out exactly how it treats the bounds.

Comment: @Tikhon - but that doesn't necessarily mean reading that much code, and the code is right there. Meaning there can be a trade-offs. Usually heavily one-sided in favor of using existing functions rather than re-inventing the wheel, but there are exceptions. This gets very obvious in C++, with some of the more trivial "algorithms" in the standard library - using them can occasionally be more verbose and less clear that writing the code directly.

Comment: +1 this answer is much better than mine!

Comment: +1 Very true! Similarly, implicit type conversion in C++ can make your code more compact but often you have to look at the code very carefully to know what is really going on in the background. In this case complexity is just hidden, not removed. I always use implicit type conversion with care.

Comment: What I like most about this answer (and why I accepted it) was because of the definition of simplicity.  It helps me see that simplicity can be either more abstract or more concrete.  My line of thinking in regards to simplicity wasn't well formed and this has helped a lot.

Comment: @Steve314: `[a..b]` is [syntactic sugar](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10) for `enumFromTo a b`, so they are exactly the same.

Comment: @hammar - OK, well I assume this isn't a circular definition thing, so I guess I should stick to the claim that the implementation of enumFromTo might make the precise bounds more clear - and hope like hell that enumFromTo isn't a primitive.

Answer (score 13):

If your coding standard is about "Readability, Maintainability, Reliability, and Performance" **then just state that**.

Don't try and prescribe how to achieve these things as there will always be situations where there is a counter example.

What you do need to prescribe is things that will cause code to break if not adhered too. Stylistic traits will not break code and should be suggestions (as long as a majority of the team agree that it is Readability the rest should be developer preference (with code review so that peer pressure reminds people that other people need to read the code)).

Comment: That was the goal that I aimed for and that was the stated object.  Simplicity (or rather, the one function/operation per line) seemed to naturally follow from that goal.  I'm trying to ascertain whether my understanding was invalid.  When you're building a coding standards, establishing a set of rules and guidelines is the entire point of the exercise.  Setting rules and guidelines that are too vague is useless.  As such, this answer really doesn't help.

Comment: My argument is that setting rules that are too strict is worse than useless and is actually harmful. Setting rules like one statement per line is stylistic. This is the thing that should definitely **NOT** be in the code guidelines. It provides not actual benefit and can be harmful to readability and maintainability if applied without thought.

Comment: +1 (because I can't +10) A common mistake I see with new programming managers is that they try to codify every last detail. The best coding standards are more like fortune cookies than recipes.

Comment: "Coding styles and standards" was the name of the document.  Obviously this isn't a standard (as in "Never use GoTo" or "Never use short ints") but a style.  Unifying style is important to readability and maintainability.

Comment: Style Guide: "This project uses tabs/spaces (choose one). This project uses the brace style K&R/Allman/BSD/GNU (choose one). Please don't not add empty spaces on the end of lines. Please keep your code neat and readable. Everything will be code reviewed by two team members and yourself: for readability/maintainability you need a majority 2/3 to check in code, For Reliability, and Performance you need 3/3 (Please provide appropriate tests to prove). More rules will be added if these are abused :-)" Done.

Comment: Readability always trump's rules about readability. As Supreme Court Justice "Potter Stewart" said: "I can not define pornography (un-readable code) code but I know it when I see it".

Answer (score 7):

Less "stuff per line", simplicity, and readability are not the same thing.  One can take an incredibly complicated obscure undocumented algorithm and code it with 1 statement per line instead of 2, and it won't become that much more readable.

Less "stuff per line" also might require supplying developers with great big tall monitors to see code blocks now spread out more vertically.  Or cause eye strain from reading tinier fonts.

Readability is it's very own metric, which often requires a compromise among several other more easily measurable metrics.  Pre-constrain all those other metrics, and the compromise no longer becomes possible, resulting in less readable code.

Answer (score 6):

If I go for simplicity, I can write code like this:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But if I go for readability, I will prefer this:

```
1e43
```

On the other hand, `1000` is much more readable and simple than `1e3` unless you work with numbers in scientific notation all the time.

This is a degenerate example of much more general pattern you can find almost anywhere -- building something out of very simple blocks can quickly become unreadable/inefficient/bad in a lot of different ways. Generalizing and reusing, on the other hand, is harder at first ("wtf is `e`?! did they mean to write `1343`?" someone might say), but can help a lot in the long run.

Comment: Your point about "1e3" being less readable than "100" is well put. In fact, this is a great example of how cognitive load influences readability. "1e3" requires reading 3 characters, AND translating the exponentiation. Reading "100" requires reading 3 characters, and no further evaluation.

Comment: Stephen, actually when reading a three-digit number like `100` you have to perform two multiplications and two additions (`0+10*(0+10*1)`). However, having used to this notation, you don't even notice that. This again shows how subjective the notion of simplicity can be.

Comment: Interesting. So, strictly speaking, "100" requires 2 multiplication (1 * 100, 0 * 10), and 2 addition operations. "1e3" requires one multiplication operation. So, absent any cognitive *context*, "100" is harder to read than "1e3". But! If you include context-switching cognitive load, the calculation is different. Since we normally read integers in non-scientific form, "100" is easier. But, if we are writing an engineering app in which all numbers are expressed in scientific notation, the "1e3" form is easier!

Answer (score 5):

Always? - NO

Ironically, attaining the right level of simplicity can be a complex undertaking. I think the key is in moderation.  Simplicity can also be in the eye of the beholder, so if you find yourself over-thinking it - just leave it alone or come back to it later.

Personally, when I try to go back and simplify something that I've written I focus on areas where I changed my mind or tried a couple of things to get what I wanted.  Those areas can usually be smoothed out.  Then just make a couple of passes through the code to make it more readable without spreading things out so much that you're jumping all over the place to figure out what's happening on a debug.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.  If you've got a complex operation, that complexity has to go somewhere.  Reducing the number of "stuff" that goes on one line just means it will take up more lines, which can actually be detrimental to code readability if it makes your routine too "tall" to fit on one screen.

Comment: Complexity is not irreducible.  We have "abstraction" and "chunking" and "organization" to try to manage complexity.  I would think that a complex operation can be described in a number of simpler steps.  It works for many real-world physical processes: summaries, overviews, etc.

Comment: @S.Lott: True, but enough scrolling and Ctrl-clicking could make a "simplified" process more difficult to follow. I've seen it happen once or twice (it's not common but it can be very frustrating to work with when it goes too far).

Comment: "scrolling and Ctrl-clicking could make a "simplified" process more difficult to follow.".  Ample evidence that it **wasn't** simplified.  I think you're confusing "simplified" with "reworked without careful thought or planning".  Simplification (through abstraction, chunking, summarization, etc.) is a very real thing.  People use it every day to cope with things like traffic, restaurants and television.  Also -- per your example -- there are bad attempts that do not actually simplify.  Those are simply bad.  Not a refutation of the argument that actual simpler  is actually more readable.

Comment: -1: This is often used as an excuse for being too lazy to break it into smaller units that are simple.

Comment: @S.Lott - there are still bounds to how far complexity can be reduced. You can eliminate unnecessary complexity, but you can only manage (not eliminate) necessary complexity - the complexity that is inherent in the requirements. Arguably, the mechanisms to manage complexity also increase complexity - some added complexity is involved in moving irrelevant complexity out of the way to better reveal the relevant details for a particular aspect/issue/construct.

Comment: @Steve314: There is no "necessary complexity".  That's just a failure to create sensible, useful, meaningful abstractions or chunks or whatever.  Physics, for example, is hellishly complex if we include all the details.  Yet, we can teach small children to push fragile things away from the edge of a table with devolving into mutual attraction, gravity and the grand unification theory of all forces.

Comment: @S.Lott - Well, it's certainly true that you can represent any requirement you want with a zero-complexity (completely empty) source file. But since you need a very specific language to get your requirements fulfilled, all you're doing is moving your requirements into the language specification.

Comment: @S.Lott - Even in physics, `G=0` looks simple enough, but what does it mean? Wierd as relativity can seem at times, it certainly doesn't mean gravity's a myth. Abstraction has done its job, but if you want to predict real-world gravitational effects, you can't abstract away the particular masses, positions, velocities etc. The complexity is still inherent in the requirements. As for your analogy, the fact that we don't necessarily need perfect precision is a part of the requirements, and a part of what defines necessary vs. unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Steve314: "what does it mean?"  Exactly.  Good example of chunking and abstraction.  I see that you agree that physics involves a great deal of simplification to make it readable.  Real world predictions are always done from models which always simplify or abstract out some details.  Always.  Astronomy ignores quantum effects.  Most electrical and solid-state physicals will ignore gravity.  I'm not sure why you provide such good examples of abstraction and simplification and then  claim it doesn't exist.

Comment: @S.Lott - if you're claiming that you can predict the position of Jupiter on Christmas Day using nothing but `G=0`, I think you're insane. If you're not, you're missing my point. Certainly you can abstract away irrelevant detail, but it's not irrelevant if your requirements say it's relevant. If you read back, I never claimed that all complexity is necessary - only that some complexity is inherent in the requirements and cannot be eliminated.

Comment: @Steve314: You can abstract away *relevant* detail.  Period.  We do it every day.  That's how our brains work.  We simplify to make the world understandable/readable.  Every day.  No complexity is "inherent" or "irreducible".  Physics stands as my proof.  Many, many branches of physics all work fine while treating the other branch as an detail to be abstracted away.  Astronomers and Solid State physicists each intentionally simplify away a serious complexity.

Answer (score 2):

> **Does simplicity always improve readability?**

No. I have seen plenty of cases where doing multiple simpler things on one line is less complex than having multiple lines.

There is a tradeoff between less code and simpler code.

In general, I would recommend going for simpler code unless you're sure doing it in fewer lines is better. I would much rather have "too verbose" code over "too complex" code.

Answer (score 2):

*Clarity + Standards + Code Re-use + Good Comments + Good Design*  could improve *readability*.

Simplicity is not always in the hand of the developer because the nature of algorithms and the complexity of application structure these days.

Take the simple web pages that perform simple tasks. Given a sort routine, it is not possible to simplify the logic, but you can make it clearer with comments, using meaningful variable names, having it written in a structured manner, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[**"Make things as simple as possible, but no simpler"**](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/#more-2363) - An often paraphrase of Albert Einstein

Simplicity improves *everything*. For differing values of simplicity, of course. Is it less lines of code? Maybe. Is it a smaller executable? Possibly. Is it something your team needs to agree upon? **Absolutely**.

Comment: +1 for the quote, but does simplicity improve readability?

Comment: "Make things as simple as possible then simplify them" is a better paraphrase as SW engineers are prone to over engineering.

Comment: I wish people would stop saying "make things as simple as possible, but no simpler".  Can't we at least generalize to MakeAsGoodAsPossibleButNoMoreSo<Thing,Attribute> as our go to uselessly general engineering tip?  (Sorry @Jesse C. Slicer, you are far from the only person to quote this, so you don't really deserve the mini-rant more than anyone else).

Answer (score 1):

Does simplicity always improve readability? Yes.  Is one statement per line always simpler? No.  Quite a few languages have a ternary operator, which, once grasped, is simpler and easier to understand than the equivalent if/else assignments.

In languages that allow multiple variables to be set on one line, doing so is frequently simpler and easir to understand than whatever the equivalent is.

Another example: regular expressions do a lot, typically in just one line, and the equivalent without a regex is frequently *much* harder to read.  /\d{3}[ -]\d{3}-\d{4}/ is the equivalent of a function call with several comments at the least, and is easier to understand than the corresponding function body.

Answer (score 1):

Readability and simplicity are subjective terms which, depending on the person and the context, usually but not always go together.

A more objective term is conciseness - something you could in principle count by counting characters, though there are some flaws in that. Conciseness seems to imply simplicity and readability, but there are (at least in my opinion) exceptions.

A longer (and arguably more complex) piece of code can be more readable if it better expresses intent. Whether your definition of simplicity cares about intent is another subjective thing - you could define complexity in terms of the syntactic structure and information-theory entropy, for instance, with no reference to intentions at all.

So, a well-chosen longer variable name may...

- Improve readability by better expressing intent
- Reduce conciseness - it is longer, after all
- Have no effect on syntactic simplicity at all - the syntactic structure of the code is unchanged

Similarly, I might write `if (some_boolean == true)`. In comparison with the equivalent alternative `if (some_boolean)`, this...

- Reduces conciseness
- Reduces syntactic simplicity, but
- May improve readability by better expressing intent.

Of course this one will trigger a mass protest - to plenty of people, this *always* damages readability too. To me, it depends a lot on the source of the boolean - e.g. the variable name (or method name or whatever) may not clearly express that the value is "truth value". Sure, the `if` tells you something, but it still smells. But plenty of people will call me an idiot for believing this.

Which is further evidence of the overall subjectivity, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're all missing some [fundamental definitions](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy). Simple, from the root *sim-plex*, means **one fold**. Simple means **doing one thing**. Easy, from the root *ease*, means **lie near**. Easy means that it is **close at hand**. The examples of *simple* code given in other answers aren't exactly what they appear.

Take [rotsor's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123473/4598) display of a very large value. He says this is *simple*. Is not, in my estimation, simple. It's easy. It's close at hand to type the number of required 0s.

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The *readable* version is simple. It does one thing. It expresses the number by describing its size in a notation purpose built for this function.

```
1e43
```

Could you describe [Aidan's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123452/4598) "simple" code snippet as doing one thing? It contains 10 lines of code (not counting comments) and at least 7 blocks (as I'd count them). If you follow the comments, you'd see that it does at least 4 things!

```
count :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
count [] = [[]]
count (x:xs) =
  -- get all possible sequences for the remaining digits
  let
    remDigits :: [[Integer]]
    remDigits = count xs
  in
  -- pull out a possible sequence for the remaining digits
  do nextDigits <- remDigits
     -- pull out all possible values for the current digit
     y <- [0..x]
     -- record that "current digit" : "remaining digits" is
     -- a valid output.
     return (y:nextDigits)
```

But, one of the recommendations for rewriting this code was one statement. Aidan does state that a reader would have to be or become familiar with monadic statements, pointer free code, etc. That's fine. Those concepts are singular and independent to learn.

```
count = mapM (enumFromTo 0)
```

You'll find that truly *simple* code is more readable than *easy* code because it does only one thing. You may need to go off and learn more "one things" to *understand* the simple code. But it should always be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

> Does simplicity always improve readability?

I would say, maybe with a little bit of controversy, **absolutely not**.

You could hand me a class with 200 member functions in its public interface, and it may be the most humanly-readable public interface out there. It might be a joy just casually reading through such code and its documentation. However, I wouldn't call it "simple", because in spite of the readability, I would have to be concerned with how all these functions interact with each other, and potentially watch out for tricky edge cases resulting from misuse.

I would prefer a class with 20 member functions that weren't so easy to read to 200 that are, because "readability" is not the top priority to me in terms of preventing human error and improving the maintainability of code (the ease at which we can change it, i.e.).

However, this is all going to hinge on our personal definition of "simplicity". "Readability" typically doesn't vary *that* wildly among us, unless someone has acquired so much expertise and fluency that they consider regex to be very "readable", e.g., forgetting the rest of us mere mortals.

**Simplicity**

There was a time, long ago, where I thought "simplicty" meant "as easy to read as possible". So I would write C code with a lot of convenience functions, trying to improve the syntax and make things as easy to read and write as possible.

I designed very big, rich, high-level libraries as a result, trying to model a function for every natural human thought: helpers upon helpers upon helpers, all to shape the client code to a more readable syntax. The code I wrote back then may have been the most "readable", yet it was also the most "unmaintainable" and "complex".

**Lisp**

Yet I had a brief passion with LISP around the mid-90s (latecomer). It changed my whole idea of "simplicity".

LISP is *not* the most readable language. Hopefully no one thinks that extracting CDRs and CARs while invoking a recursive function with a boatload of nested parentheses is very "readable".

Nevertheless, after struggling to get my brain wrapped around the language's odd syntax and totally recursive ways of doing things, it permanently changed my idea of simplicity.

What I found with the code I wrote in LISP is that I was no longer making subtle errors anymore, even though the trickiness of thinking that way had me making more blatant mistakes (but those are easy to spot and correct). I wasn't misunderstanding what a function was doing and missing out on a subtle, unanticipated side effect. I was just having an easier time in general making changes and writing correct programs.

After LISP, simplicity to me became about *minimalism, symmetry, flexibility, fewer side effects, fewer but more flexible functions that combine together in an infinite variety of ways.*

I came to appreciate the mindset that the most reliable code of all is code that doesn't exist. While it's only a crude metric, I tend to see the potential for unreliability of code based on its quantity. Seeking the utmost syntactical convenience and readability tends to increase that quantity by a large factor.

**Minimalism**

With the LISP mindset embedded in me, I came to prefer minimalist APIs. I'd prefer a library with fewer but more reliable, flexible functions that are less convenient and potentiality harder to read than one which offers a boatload of "convenient" helpers and such which may make the code easy to "read" but potentially trip over more issues with unreliability and surprises that result from misunderstanding what one of these thousands of functions do.

**Safety**

Another thing about LISP was safety. It promoted minimal side effects and pure functions, and that was where I no longer saw myself making subtle mistakes, even though the difficulty of reading and writing in the language increased more blatant mistakes I could spot 10 seconds later.

Pure functions and immutable states became preferable to me whenever I could afford it, even if the syntax of:

```
sword = sharpen(sword)
```

... is a little less straightforward and detached from human thinking than:

```
sharpen(sword)
```

**Readability VS. Simplicity**

Yet again, LISP is not the most "readable" language. It can pack a lot of logic into a small section of code (possibly more than one human thought per line). I tend to ideally prefer one human thought per line for "readability", but it's not necessarily for "simplicity".

With this kind of definition of "simple", sometimes "simple" might actually somewhat compete with "readable". This is considering things more from an interface design point of view.

A simple interface means you need to learn far fewer things to use it, and potentially has greater reliability and fewer gotchas as result of its minimalism. A comprehensive documentation on the subject might fit a booklet rather than a massive volume of books. Nevertheless, it might require some more grunt-work and yield less readable code.

"Simple" to me improves our ability to understand the functionality in our system at a broad level. "Readable" to me improves our ability to connect each little line of code to natural language and thought and might speed up our understanding of what one line of code does, especially if we're not fluent in the language.

Regex is an example of what I consider "extremely simple". It's "too simple and too unreadable" for my personal taste. There's a balancing act for me between these extremes, yet regex does have that LISP-like quality of simplicity as I define it: minimalism, symmetry, incredible flexibility, reliability, etc. The problem for me with regex is that it's so simple that it has become so unreadable to the point where I don't think I'll ever become fluent at it (my brain just doesn't work that way and I envy people who can write regex code fluently).

So anyway, that's my definition of "simplicity", and it is completely independent of "readability" and may sometimes even interfere with the other, leading to a balancing act between a more "syntactically convenient" and readable but bigger library or a "syntactically inconvenient", less readable, yet smaller library. I've always found the true "convenience of understanding" and true "maintainability" priorities to align with the latter, with the strong preference towards minimalism even at some cost to readability and more natural human syntax (but not to the point of regex). YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Always? - YES

Attaining the right level of simplicity is a complex and difficult undertaking. But always worthwhile since it always improves readability.   I think the key is deep understanding. Simplicity is an absolute, measured by "new concepts" per "chunk" of code.  A few new concepts means simpler.

Focus on areas where there are a dense cluster of concepts and find ways to "chunk" or "summarize" or "abstract".  Make a couple of passes through the code to make it simpler and more readable.

A good abstraction is worth it's weight in gold.  A good abstraction makes this simpler -- and consequently more readable.

Comment: I can't help thinking that your scare-quotes are there because you're aware that "concept" and "chunk" are themselves subjective. One persons single concept is another persons amalgam of three distinct ideas. It's hard to have an absolute and objective measure of subjective stuff.

Comment: @Steve314: Scare quotes?  No. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking all seem to be similar in that they describe simplification through chunking.  (Except the guitar technique, that seems different.)  The quotes are there because there are so many alternate terms for abstraction, chunking, summarizing, etc.  If I pick just one everyone objects that abstraction isn't the same thing as chunking.  The quotes are there to emphasize that this is somehow debatable.  Yet.  It's clearly done all the time and seems to be a natural human tendency.

Comment: What I don't deny - chunking is done all the time and is a good idea. What I deny - that there's a definitive objective rule for where the boundaries should be between chunks. My arguments may be more pedantic than helpful, but I still doubt the "always" in "always improves readability".

Comment: @Steve314: We always abstract, chunk and summarize to help ourselves understand things.  Always.  Chunking, abstracting, summarizing ("simplifying") is something we always do.  We just do.  It's how our brains apprehend reality.  Simplification always improves readability, and can always be done.

Comment: yes, we do. I never said otherwise.

Comment: @Steve314: What does `but I still doubt the "always"` mean?  We always do it.  It's hard to see a time when we don't do it.  Do you have an example of when we fail to chunk, abstract or summarize?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that once you've "abstracted detail away" from one particular chunk, that detail still exists somewhere else and still has to be managed - plus you also have the complexity of dealing with the abstraction mechanism. That's less simplicity, yet (done properly) more readability. Moving detail somewhere else **doesn't eliminate it** - it still exists, just in a different place. It's obviously useful for managing complexity, but it isn't magic.

Comment: @Steve314: No one said it was "eliminated" (I don't think).  It was made "readable".  That's the point.  And it's always made readable.

Comment: Actually, I see my mistake. Your answer starts by stating "Always? - YES", meaning that simplicity always == readability. But in your "always worthwhile since it always improves readability" line, which my 'I still doubt the "always"' references, you say "the **right** level of simplicity" (my emphasis). If you're contradicting yourself, and the right level isn't always the minimum so that similicity and readability don't necessarily go together, then I was mistaken in my 'I doubt the "always"'. The right (but not necessarily minimal) level of simplicity is necessary for optimal readability.

Comment: @Steve314: You win the sophistry award in my book.  Simplicity always means readability.  It's the way our brains work.  Achieving it is hard.  But simplicity == readability.  Always.  Because our brains always work that way.  Always.

Comment: a sophistry award from you is something to by truly proud of, but I still have doubts. A longer variable name improves readability, but does it improve simplicity? Only if you define simplicity in a way that ensures that, which is circular. There's cases where more complexity means more readability, such as your own abstracting-away-details arguments elsewhere in this question - you seem to claim moving the details somewhere else means they don't exist, though you've denied that here. As we clearly won't agree on this, it's time to exchange sophistry medals and move on.

Comment: "you seem to claim moving the details somewhere else means they don't exist".  False.  Sorry.  Every day, every human simplifies the world to make it readable/understandable.  Every day.  Every human.  Simplicity == Readability.  They're not "circular".  They're the same thing.  A longer name is only "more complex"  if somehow "concept" == "letter".  True when learning to read.  Not true when documenting software.

Comment: and insisting that there is no subjectivity in the definition of "simplicity", and that only your definition is valid, doesn't count as sophistry? It's not just me - others have acknowledged that a little extra complexity, e.g. to better express intent, can improve readability in some cases.

Comment: I didn't realize that I had insisted that there is no subjectivity in the definition of "simplicity".  I'm not sure that it matters.  I'm trying to make one tiny point.  Simplicity is **always** more readable.  That's all.  You can read more into it, I suppose.  But I'm really only making one claim.  If it's simpler, then it's easier to read.  That's it.

Answer (score -2):

The questions reminds me of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46460/7816) on Stack Overflow, particularly this quote (substitute quality with simplicity):

> Quality -- you know what it is, yet you don't know what it is. But
>   that's self- contradictory. But some things are better than others,
>   that is, they have more quality. But when you try to say what the
>   quality is, apart from the things that have it, it all goes poof!
>   There's nothing to talk about. But if you can't say what Quality is,
>   how do you know what it is, or how do you know that it even exists? If
>   no one knows what it is, then for all practical purposes it doesn't
>   exist at all. But for all practical purposes it really does exist.
>   What else are the grades based on? Why else would people pay fortunes
>   for some things and throw others in the trash pile? Obviously some
>   things are better than others -- but what's the ``betterness''? -- So
>   round and round you go, spinning mental wheels and nowhere finding
>   anyplace to get traction. What the hell is Quality? What is it?

I think that it's important that you keep in mind that a codified coding standard for all its benefits will not make good programmers out of bad ones. A word like 'simple' may be interpreted differently by different people (see Aidan Cully's answer), but that may not be such a bad thing. Junior programmers will still need to have their code reviewed by senior programmers and learn why the senior programmers interpretation of 'simple' is better than their own.

Comment: This is why I defined simplicity in the question.

Answer (score -2):

One function call per line is simpler? Let's try an example!

```
=== One call per line ===
x = y.getThis()
a = x.getThat()
b = a.getSomethingElse()

=== Less "simple" version ===
b = y.getThis().getThat().getSomethingElse()
```

What do you think? Is one call per line actually simpler?

Comment: Yes.  One call per line is simpler and easier for me to read.  However, readability *is* subjective.  (Also, this doesn't even come close to answering the question.)

Comment: Hi Stephen, can you elaborate on how you think this answers the question? It's not clear what you you're trying to point out here.

Comment: @MarkTrapp No problem. The original question proposed a single-function-per-line approach. The example I posted shows the same two code snippets, one implemented as single-function-per-line, the other as chained-method-calls. I think the chained call is a lot easier to read: short, devoid of unnecessary temporary variables, and elegant.

Comment: If you have to chain getters then your code is pooly designed